# How to view the underlying regex patterns used by ctags for a built-in supported language?

Tags: ctags

How does one actually view the patterns used to define parsing and tag-generation for a built-in ctags-supported language? `ctags --list-kinds-full=$LANG` gives us kind definitions, but what about the pattern-matching itself?

Comment: I'd start with the source code for ctags itself, under https://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/code/HEAD/tree/trunk and then the $LANG.c file for the language you're interested in. E.g: https://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/python.c